# Ionic 2 login with Laravel 5.4 as backend

Tags: php, api, typescript, ionic2, laravel-5.4

I am new to ionic 2 and laravel 5.4

I am trying to create a register, login and dashboard of a user.
When I trying to create login, it says `tokenMismatchException`.
Now, how can I pass a csrf token from ionic to laravel?

here is my method inside login.ts

```
login() {
  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
  let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  let data = {
    username: this.username,
    password: this.password,
    // can i pass token here to laravel?
  }

  this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/api/login', data, options)
    .subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res);
     }, error => {
      console.log(error);// Error getting the data
  });
}
```

In my  route inside api.php in laravel

```
Route::post('login','ApiController@login');
```

In my api controller

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    echo json_encode($request->username);
    // how to create login auth here? from ionic 2?
}
```

Problem 1: `tokenMismatchException`

Problem 2: I don't know how to create login using ionic 2 and laravel 5.4 as backend.

Is anyone here can give me resources about ionic 2 + laravel 5.4 login auth or can solve the problem?
Thanks and keep share your ideas to help programmers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an answer here https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps.

This might be a good resource for beginners like me because of its step-by-step tutorial.